# Two spinners are opened at the same time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I have two drop down spinner menus and when i press them both at the same time they display their drop down menus. Is there a way of setting it so that only one can be opened at a time? I have tried setting setEnabled(false) and setClickable(false) but you can still open the two of them at the same time. Anyone know is it possible to stop this happening?

Comment: Under normal circumstances only one spinner can be opened at a time

Comment: please put up some code of your xml containing spinners

Comment: this is not enough information, please put up some code of your xml containing spinners